# How to check logs inside ECS Fargate container?

Tags: logging, cluster-computing, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm running a springboot application in a ECS fargate cluster. Is there any way I can log into Fargate docker container to see the logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to check your container logs is by flagging the checkbox to send them to CloudWatch (this can be done at the container level configuration in the task definition): [image]

Alternatively, if your log is in a specific file and not printed to `stdout` you can use [ECS exec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html) to get a shell inside the container and do your analysis from within.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Able to proceed further.